# Always show 'Open With' in right-click context menu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

Sometimes, Windows 10 will not show the 'Open With' sub-menu in the right-click context menu for some file types, and sometimes when I select multiple files of a specific type.

Is there any way to force the 'Open With' sub-menu to *always* appear no matter the file type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try shift + right-click ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem:

Follow These steps:

1. Click Start, All Programs, Accessories, Notepad.
2. Copy and paste this text:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]
@="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"

3. Click File, Save As, name the file "OpenWith.reg" (WITH THE QUOTATION MARKS) and click OK.
4. Now double-click OpenWith.reg, click Continue, Yes, OK, and see if the problem is solved.

NOTE: DON'T USE ANY REGISTRY CLEANER ON THE SYSTEM.

Comment: Hi, this did not work. A file type this consistently happens with is an SVG file. Create more than one SVG file, select them, right click, and see how the 'Open With' sub-menu is not there. It's not just SVG files this happens with, it's sporadic. I just want to be able to easily decide what I want to open the files with, without going to the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `shift`+`right clic` ?
It should show you extra menu items, with `open with` item for any files if you are lucky.

Comment: Nope. That does not work. Thank you nonetheless.