# Windows10: Context menu does not show "Open With" for folders

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I rarely use the "Open With"-menu in ctxtmn, but when I recently wanted to open it for a folder, I noticed it's not there (for folders). Or maybe the context menu for folders does not have "Open with"-menu?

FWIW, I read the answers to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1090404/always-show-open-with-in-right-click-context-menu-on-windows-10) similar Q and they did not help. (Shift+click does not show it, the registry key `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With]` exists and has the value `{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}`.

Is there anything else I could try?

P.S: O/S is  Windows 10 Professional, 64-bit, Release 2009, Build 19043.1320, .NET v4.8.04084. (*In case you wonder why I would want to use "Open With" for a folder: I installed Corel's PaintShop Pro 2022 and suddenly every folder is opened with PSP. Corel's support suggested to look at the "Open With"-menu - but I can't...*)

Answer (score 1):

"Open with" determines which program is associated with a file type by default. It is also used to choose among different programs associated with the same file type. It is designed to work for a single file, so it won't be available in the folder context menu.

Comment: Ah, ok - so may panic was unmotivated.